# Read Clojure source code one token at a time

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, it's possible to read a whole s-expression with `(read)`. Is there some way to read just one token at a time? So calling `(read-token "(read)")` would return something like `["(", "read", ")"]`.

Comment: Take a look at instaparse https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse

Comment: Not sure if this is suitable for your purpose, but you could at least read in the source as a string and then operate on its characters.

Comment: @NateW. That still requires lexically analyzing the string, which is what I'm trying to avoid having to do.

Answer (score 2):

"tokens" are not something that the clojure reader works with: it doesn't have distinct lex/parse phases like languages with more complicated grammars often do. Of course you can write your own grammar for clojure forms, call `(` an `OPEN_PAREN` token and so on, but there's no built-in support for it.